# JSON error while trying to fetch jsonarray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to fetch array from json object but get error

When I do `jarray2 = object1.getJSONArray(route);`

I get the following error

APP CRASH: No value for (the following JSON)

```
[{
    "options": {
        "allowUTurn": false
    },
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 52.42252295423907,
        "lng": 4.873809814453125
    },
    "name": "Coenplein, A10, Amsterdam, Noord, Amsterdam, MRA, Stadsregio Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands, 1035RN, The Netherlands",
    "_initHooksCalled": true
}, {
    "options": {
        "allowUTurn": false
    },
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 52.28674750920209,
        "lng": 4.941873550415039
    },
    "name": "Holendrechterzijweg, Ouderkerk aan de Amstel, Ouder-Amstel, MRA, Stadsregio Amsterdam, North Holland, Netherlands, 1191LJ, The Netherlands",
    "_initHooksCalled": true
}, {
    "options": {
        "allowUTurn": false
    },
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 52.0727536539532,
        "lng": 4.32861328125
    },
    "name": "87, Zwetstraat, Rivierenbuurt, The Hague, MRDH, South Holland, Netherlands, 2515VE, The Netherlands",
    "_initHooksCalled": true
}]
```

Here is the code

```
try
    {
        object1 = new JSONObject(response);
        jarray1 = object1.getJSONArray("selected_route_data");
        for(int i=0;i<jarray1.length();i++)
        {
            json1 = jarray1.getJSONObject(i);
            String route_id = json1.getString("route_id").toString();
            String route_name = json1.getString("route_name").toString();
            String route = json1.getString("route_data").toString();

            jarray2 = object1.getJSONArray(route);

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e("APP CRASH", e.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: on which `json` you are working? Post the `json`.

Comment: This JSON does not have any of the fields you are requesting so please post the right one

Comment: Your base is an array, not an object. You also do not have any of the elements you are looking for in your individual objects.

Comment: I don't think `"selected_route_data"` is the array that you want.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the JSON you are attempting to parse does not contain the values you are looking for. None of the elements in the array contain either `route_id`, `route_name` or `route_data`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if an element exists in the JSON you are parsing, you can do something like

```
String route_id = null;
if (!json1.optString("route_id").isEmpty()) {
   route_id = json1.getString("route_id").toString();
}
```